# Php Yii2 Get facebook status based from searched word

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii2

I'm trying to make a system were a user inputs a word in the search bar and the system returns a number of status from facebook were that word occurs.

I am using kartik's social plugin for that matter.

```
http://demos.krajee.com/social-details/facebook#usage
```

However this line of code below only embeds a certain post from facebook post that i chose.

```
<?php 
   //this only embeds a certain post from facebook post that i chose
   echo FacebookPlugin::widget(['type'=>FacebookPlugin::POST, 'settings' => ['href'=>'https://www.facebook.com/RodrigoDuterteUpdates/posts/301638660198517']]);
?>
```

Is it possible to get a facebook status based from searched word.?

Comment: No, Graph API doesn’t offer that kind of search.